# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript

No me funciona lo siguiente, por lo que asumo allí está el fallo `{{ Form::text('width[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'onKeyUp' => 'basePrice()']) }}` esta es la función a la que intento llamar `onKeyUp="basePrice()"`

Error que me muestra la consola:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
at basePrice (invoice:272)
at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup (invoice:107)
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function basePrice() {
   var width = document.invoice.width.value;
   var height = document.invoice.height.value;
   try{
       width = (isNaN(parseInt(width)))? 0 : parseInt(width);
       height = (isNaN(parseInt(height)))? 0 : parseInt(height);
       metros_lineales = (width/1000) * 180000;
       metros_cuadrados = (width * height) / 1000000;
       subtotal = metros_cuadrados * 100000;
       total = metros_lineales + subtotal * 1,025;
       document.invoice.unit_price.value = total + 480000;
   }
   catch(e) {}
}
</script>
```

Formulario

```
<div class="table-responsive-sm">
    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'invoice.store', 'name' => 'invoice']) !!}

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sistema</th>
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                    <th>Ancho (mm)</th>
                    <th>Alto (mm)</th>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                    <th>Precio Unitario</th>
                    <th>Precio Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="form">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ Form::text('type[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}</td>
                    <td>{{ Form::text('description[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}</td>
                    <td>{{ Form::text('width', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'onkeyup' => 'basePrice()']) }}</td>
                    <td>{{ Form::text('height', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'onkeyup' => 'basePrice()']) }}</td>
                    <td>{{ Form::text('quantity', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'onkeyup' => 'basePrice()']) }}</td>
                    <td>{{ Form::text('unit_price', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}</td>
                    <td>{{ Form::text('total_price', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}</td>
               </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
       <div class="form-row">
           <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pb-4 text-center">
               <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary add_button col-md-2 col-xs-12"> Agregar Ítem</a>
           </div>
       </div>
                
       <div class="col-12 mt-4 text-center"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Generar Cotización</button></div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Comment: No sé  si tenga que ver, pero es todo en minúscula. Prueba `onkeyup` en vez de `onKeyUp`.

Comment: Gracias, he hecho lo que dicen, no da error en la consola, los escibí en minúscula y aún nada, lo extraño es que me funciona pperfectamente en el archivo donde lo hice por separado, ahora cuando lo estoy incorporando donde va, no funciona.

Comment: Hice un cambio y ahora si me muestra un error, lo agrego a la pregunta.

Comment: Agrega el js donde planeas manipular algún value, no se si sea el código de la función `basePrice()` pero por ahi podemos empezar

Comment: Lo acabo de agregar

Comment: Haciendo varios intentos y cambios, logré resolver parcialmente... Eliminando los corchetes `[ ]` en el nombre del `input` `with[]` funciona `{{ Form::text('width', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'onKeyUp' => 'basePrice()']) }}`, como hago para poder mantenerlos? porque necesito guardar varios datos

Comment: Necesitas agregar código del formulario para ver en qué contenedor tienes el _input_ y poder decirte cómo acceder a todos los elementos.

Comment: Hola @Triby ya lo agregué

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuelve a colocar los corchetes en los nombres de campo y agrega un parámetro a la función `basePrice(event)`.

```
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sistema</th>
                <th>Descripción</th>
                <th>Ancho (mm)</th>
                <th>Alto (mm)</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Precio Unitario</th>
                <th>Precio Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="form">
            <tr>
                <td>{{ Form::text('type[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}</td>
                <td>{{ Form::text('description[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}</td>
                <td>{{ Form::text('width[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'onkeyup' => 'basePrice(event)']) }}</td>
                <td>{{ Form::text('height[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'onkeyup' => 'basePrice(event)']) }}</td>
                <td>{{ Form::text('quantity[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'onkeyup' => 'basePrice(event)']) }}</td>
                <td>{{ Form::text('unit_price[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}</td>
                <td>{{ Form::text('total_price[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}</td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
```

Dentro de la función usas el evento para acceder al contenedor común de todos los *inputs*, la fila. `event.target` es el elemento que disparó el evento y llegas al padre usando `.closest('tr')`.

Desde el *tr* accedes a cada elemento por su nombre con `.querySelector()`

```js
function basePrice(event) {
   // Obtener contenedor padre (TR)
   let tr = event.target.closest('tr');
   // Obtener campos necesarios desde TR
   var width = tr.querySelector('[name="width[]"]').value;
   var height = tr.querySelector('[name="height[]"]').value;
   try{
       width = (isNaN(parseInt(width)))? 0 : parseInt(width);
       height = (isNaN(parseInt(height)))? 0 : parseInt(height);
       metros_lineales = (width/1000) * 180000;
       metros_cuadrados = (width * height) / 1000000;
       subtotal = metros_cuadrados * 100000;
       total = metros_lineales + subtotal * 1,025;
       tr.querySelector('[name="unit_price[]"]').value = total + 480000;
   }
   catch(e) {}
}
```

```html
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sistema</th>
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                    <th>Ancho (mm)</th>
                    <th>Alto (mm)</th>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                    <th>Precio Unitario</th>
                    <th>Precio Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="form">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="type[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="description[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="width[]" onkeyup="basePrice(event);"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="height[]" onkeyup="basePrice(event);"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" onkeyup="basePrice(event);"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="unit_price[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="total_price[]"></td>
               </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="type[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="description[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="width[]" onkeyup="basePrice(event);"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="height[]" onkeyup="basePrice(event);"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" onkeyup="basePrice(event);"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="unit_price[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="total_price[]"></td>
               </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
```

Comment: Mil gracias @Triby funciona perfecto